# Find most recently accessed file from give files in C

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

How to get most recently accessed file in Linux?

I used `stat()` call checking for `st_atime`, but it is not updating if i open and read the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your filesystem is mounted with the [`noatime`](http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec73.html) or [`relatime`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/Relatime.html) option:

```
greek0@orest:/home/greek0$ cat /proc/mounts
/dev/md0 / ext3 rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
...
```

These mount options are often used because they increase filesystem performance. Without them, every single read of a file turns into a write to the disk (for updating the atime).

In general, you can't rely on atime to have any useful meaning on most computers.

If it's Ok to only detect accesses to files that happen while your program is running, you can look into [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify). It provides a method to be notified of currently ongoing filesystem accesses.

If that doesn't satisfy your requirements, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Can you suggest any easy way to do this. I checked file system is mounted using relatime.

Comment: With ``relatime``, the ``atime`` is only updated if the file was modified since the last read, or if ``atime`` hasn't been updated within 24 hours. In other words, it's not reliable. What do you plan to do with the ``atime`` information? Maybe there is another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: given a list of files as command line argument to C program i want to file which is most recently accessed

Comment: But what do you want to do with that information? What action do you take depending which file was most recently opened?

Comment: I am asked to write simple c code to do this. I think there is no straight answer for this i need to explain this. What you say?

Comment: Updated my answer, check out inotify. Further, if you only need this on one computer, just remove ``relatime`` from the mount options and live with the decreases speed. But if you want to distribute your program to others, ``atime`` will be mostly useless.